# R - how do I find the second derivative of a numeric array

Tags: r, calculus, differentiation

I have an array of numeric data (as it happens Option Call prices organized by Strike).

I'd like to compute the second deriviative in R.

I was able to fit a smooth curve e.g.

```
call.lo <- loess(mid ~ strike, df.x, model=T)
```

but am stuck going from that to differentiation.

any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want the [discrete second derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference)?

```
 mid <- 1:100; strike <- (1:100)^3 + 2*(1:100)^2 + 1:100 + 5

 deriv <- function(x, y) diff(y) / diff(x)
 middle_pts <- function(x) x[-1] - diff(x) / 2
 second_d <- deriv(middle_pts(mid), deriv(mid, strike))
 smooth_second_d <- loess(second_d ~ midpts,
   data.frame(second_d = second_d, midpts = middle_pts(middle_pts(mid))), model = T)
```

Example:

```
 plot(middle_pts(middle_pts(mid)), deriv(middle_pts(mid), deriv(mid, strike)))
```

I see `6x + 4` like expected.